# how to get the three previous dates for the given date .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to get the 3 dates from the current date or if user enters a date like `16/07/2011` i would like to show the 3 previous dates for this like

`15/07/2011,14/07/2011,13/07/2011`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple steps:

- Parse the date to a `DateTime`. If you know the format to be used, I would suggest using `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`.
- Use `DateTime.AddDays(-1)` to get the previous date (either with different values from the original, or always -1 but from the "new" one each time)

For example:

```
string text = "16/07/2011";

Culture culture = ...; // The appropriate culture to use. Depends on situation.
DateTime parsed;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy", culture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                            out parsed))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(parsed.AddDays(-i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }
}
else    
{
    // Handle bad input
}
```

Comment: Can you give that culture too as per normal situation

Comment: @Vivekh: What's "normal"? If this is *direct* user input, then the user's culture would probably be appropriate - but then it *might* also be appropriate to take their normal date format, which may be "MM/dd/yyyy" for example.

Comment: Note that if the value entered was more than a date (it also specified time), then you should use the `.Date` property first.  Depending on your usage you may want to do that anyway, just to be safe.

Comment: @Merlyn: Given that we're only printing out the date afterwards, and only subtracting a number of days, I don't *think* it'll make any difference. Also note that we're explicitly parsing the input with a format which only accepts dates.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `TimeSpan` object or `AddDays` function. Here are example extension methods where you can modify days easily:

```
    public static DateTime SubtractDays(this DateTime time, int days)
    {
        return time - new TimeSpan(days, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static DateTime SubtractDays(this DateTime time, int days)
    {
        return time.AddDays(days)
    }
```

Comment: I've retracted my previous comment because I think it would be okay after all due to the way DateTime works, but in general you should be careful about the difference between subtracting "a day" and subtracting "24 hours" - they aren't always the same thing, as not all days have 24 hours (DST transitions).

Comment: The first and second implementation don't match.  You should negate days in the second example, otherwise you have to pass negative days for it to work, which I would expect to actually *add* days.